# Why do colours change their suffix?

Tags: spelling, grammar-identification

For example:

Ich habe *weiße* Milch, vs *weiß*

When you use the different *rot, rote, roten, rotes*?

I find nouns, indifinitive adjectives or whatever very confusing so if this could be explained in a very simple way, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, as you mention, in this case "weiße" is a conjugated adjective. So all rules for adjectives appply here. Or do I miss something here and your question is more specific?

Comment: ...*declinated* adjective

Comment: So in German rather than saying the white milk they normally say the milk white and have the adjective after, but when they put it before it becomes a 'declinated adjective' and adds a suffix? (-e or -en)

http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/adjectives/adjective-declensions/

This is what I have used to try and understand what a declinated adjective is but I might be completely misunderstanding.

Comment: @SelenaCox: Caution! Having the adjecitve after the noun, gives a completely different meaning, similar to english: "weiße Milch" is *white milk*, while "milchweiß" would mean something like *milke-white*, or *as white as milk*

Comment: @SelenaCox: I don't think there is much point trying to translate grammar like this into English which does not have anything like it. Just get used to it that German words (not only adjectives) can have endings depending on context.

Comment: @SelenaCox No, you will usually have the adjective in front. You only put it after if you use it with something like "to be".

Comment: The first sentence on the page you linked to is the important part: "German adjectives work just like English ones, except that they take on case endings when they come right before a noun." - Which case ending that is depends on the noun's grammatical gender, which you just have to learn, preferably right away together with the noun, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user1583209 _declined, inflected_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you will have to inflect adjectives. The case where you don't inflect them (the one mentioned in the link you posted in the comments) is when you use the adjective as a predicate:

- "Weiße Milch" - *white milk* - He're you need to inflect the adjective.
- "Milch ist weiß." - *Milk is white* - Here you're using it as a predicate and therefore don't have to inflect it.

In general, you are using the adjective predicatively if it's not in front of the noun it's describing. You will usually have that situation when you use words like "sein" (*to be*) and "werden" (*to become*): "Die Milch wird gelb." - *The milk's going yellow*.

Comment: So just so I understand what you mean, I would so 

Der Himmel ist blau und groß- for the sky is blue and big

but I would say, Der blaue Himmel ist groß. So the colour is inflected because its an adjective before a noun?

Comment: @Selena Cox Your sentences are both correct now, but the colour is **always** an adjective. All adjectives behave that way: "die schlechte Milch" (_the bad milk_) vs "Die Milch ist schlecht." (_The milk's bad._)

Comment: so that makes sense now for adding an 'e', but why when saying 'ein gelbes hemd' it has added an 'e' and a 's'

Comment: Because the correct form of adjectives in German depends on four things: a) the gender of the noun it modifies ("Milch" is feminine while "Hemd" is neuter"), b) whether the noun is singular or plural, c) the case of the noun it modifies and d) whether the article is definite (der/die/das) or indefinite (ein/eine/ein) (**die** schlechte Milch vs **ein** gelbes Hemd.)

Comment: Adjective declension is a complicated topic; but which form to use in which case is explained in the link you posted in your comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because in German adjectives are inflected.